# jquery not returning the string correctly which consists of 's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing "Uncle Bob's Organic" in **data-Iname** attribute while retrieving the same value it is retrieving up to "Uncle Bob"

Below is the process I used to retrieve the value from **data-Iname**

var iname = $(this).attr("data-Iname");

This is what i did so far !!

$(function () {
            var ItemId = 0;

```
        $("#AddItems").change(function () {
            var SelectedUserId = $("#AddItems").val();
            var SelectedItem = $("#AddItems option:selected").text();
            //alert(SelectedItem);
            var ItemName = "Uncle Bob's Organic";
            items.push(SelectedItem + '|' + SelectedUserId);
            ItemId++;
            //$("#tblItems").append("<tr id=" + ItemId + "><td id=" + ItemId + ">" + SelectedItem + '  ' + "<span class= 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash' title='Delete'></span><br></td></tr>");

            $("#AddedItems").append("<div id=div_" + ItemId + ">" + SelectedItem + '  ' + "<span class= 'remove glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id=remove_" + ItemId + " title='Delete' data-Iname='" + ItemName.toString() + "'></span><br></div>");

        });
    });

    $('.container').on('click', '.remove', function () {
        var iname = $(this).attr("data-Iname");
        var id = this.id;
        var split_id = id.split("_");
        var deleteindex = split_id[1];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            if (iname == items[i])
            {
                alert(items[i])
                items.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        alert(items);
        $("#div_" + deleteindex).remove();

    });
```

Comment: how are you setting it

Comment: Share your html code.

Comment: var ItemName = "Uncle Bob's Organic";
$("#AddedItems").append("<div id=div_" + ItemId + ">" + SelectedItem + '  ' + "<span class= 'remove glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id=remove_" + ItemId + " title='Delete' data-Iname='" + ItemName.toString() + "'></span><br></div>");

Comment: You need to escape or encode the single quote that is embedded in ItemName.

Comment: Are you assigning value after document loaded? Also can you show html that was generated?

Comment: @TimaGegewepe yes

Comment: @Naveen updated the question

Comment: Can you create a complete reproduction? For example, on CodePen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead

```
var ItemName = "Uncle Bob's Organic";
$("#AddedItems").append(
  "<div id=div_" +
    ItemId +
    ">" +
    SelectedItem +
    " " +
    "<span class= 'remove glyphicon glyphicon-trash' id=remove_" +
    ItemId +
    " title='Delete' data-Iname=\"" +
    ItemName.toString() +
    "\"></span><br></div>"
);
```

so your output was something like data-Iname = 'Uncle Bob's Organic' .. i just replaced the outer quotes with double quotes

Comment: Why escaping even needed when you can just put data-Iname=" +
    ItemName.toString() + " ? I

Comment: attribute finishes when it matches the quotes, earlier it was matching single quote , i changed it to double quote

Comment: @TimaGegewepe not sure, it has a space

Comment: Single quotes work equally as double quotes in HTML.

Comment: @ashishsingh that's dumb, I mean not your code but author's *imho

Comment: @ashishsingh I followed the process you gave, and it works perfectly it returns the string as am expecting.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović if you write  <div attr = ' bob's speec' ></div> .. attribute value will be `bob` only

Comment: @TimaGegewepe There's no reason to be disrespectful.

Comment: @ashishsingh Thanks, I see. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: cool, we have all done this double quote single quote thing i guess